# Elasticsearch match or term always failing

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a problem with a query that return no result. When I execute the following query either with `match` or `term` :

```json
{
    "size": 1, 
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                { "term": { "ALERT_TYPE.raw": "ERROR" }}
            ],
            "filter": [
                { "range": {
                    "@timestamp": {
                        "gte": "2018-02-01T00:00:01.000Z",
                        "lte": "2018-02-28T23:55:55.000Z"
                    }
                }}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I always got the following response,  :

```json
{
    "took": 92,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 215,
        "successful": 215,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 0,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    }
}
```

But i'm sure the element is present because when i do a match_all query, the first hit is the following :

```json
{
    "took": 269,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 210,
        "successful": 210,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 68292,
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "logstash-2018.02.22",
            "_type": "alert",
            "_id": "AWEdVphtJjppDZ0FiAz-",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
            "@version": "1",
            "@timestamp": "2018-02-22T10:07:41.549Z",
            "path": "/something",
            "host": "host.host",
            "type": "alert",
            "SERVER_TYPE": "STANDALONE",
            "LOG_FILE": "log.log",
            "DATE": "2018-02-22 11:02:02,367",
            "ALERT_TYPE": "ERROR",
            "MESSAGE": "There is an error"
            }
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here I can see the field is the value that I am expecting. And from the mapping I know the field is analyzed by the default analyser and the raw field is not analysed (Thanks to the answer of Glenn Van Schil). The mapping is generated dynamically by logstash but it looks like this for the type i'm looking into:

```json
  "alert": {
    "_all": {
      "enabled": true,
      "omit_norms": true
    },
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "message_field": {
          "mapping": {
            "index": "analyzed",
            "omit_norms": true,
            "fielddata": { "format": "disabled" },
            "type": "string"
          },
          "match": "message",
          "match_mapping_type": "string"
        }
      },
      {
        "string_fields": {
          "mapping": {
            "index": "analyzed",
            "omit_norms": true,
            "fielddata": { "format": "disabled" },
            "type": "string",
            "fields": {
              "raw": {
                "index": "not_analyzed",
                "ignore_above": 256,
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "match": "*",
          "match_mapping_type": "string"
        }
      }
    ],
    "properties": {
      "@timestamp": { "type": "date", "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis" },
      "@version": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
      "ALERT_TYPE": {
        "type": "string",
        "norms": { "enabled": false },
        "fielddata": { "format": "disabled" },
        "fields": {
          "raw": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "DATE": {
        "type": "string",
        "norms": { "enabled": false },
        "fielddata": { "format": "disabled" },
        "fields": {
          "raw": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "LOG_FILE": {
        "type": "string",
        "norms": { "enabled": false },
        "fielddata": { "format": "disabled" },
        "fields": {
          "raw": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "MESSAGE": {
        "type": "string",
        "norms": { "enabled": false },
        "fielddata": { "format": "disabled" },
        "fields": {
          "raw": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "SERVER_TYPE": {
        "type": "string",
        "norms": { "enabled": false },
        "fielddata": { "format": "disabled" },
        "fields": {
          "raw": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "geoip": {
        "dynamic": "true",
        "properties": {
          "ip": { "type": "ip" },
          "latitude": { "type": "float" },
          "location": { "type": "geo_point" },
          "longitude": { "type": "float" }
        }
      },
      "host": {
        "type": "string",
        "norms": { "enabled": false },
        "fielddata": { "format": "disabled" },
        "fields": {
          "raw": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "path": {
        "type": "string",
        "norms": { "enabled": false },
        "fielddata": { "format": "disabled" },
        "fields": {
          "raw": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "type": {
        "type": "string",
        "norms": { "enabled": false },
        "fielddata": { "format": "disabled" },
        "fields": {
          "raw": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
```

Does anyone have a clue about why this query keep returning nothing ? Maybe there is something in the mapping that i am missing which explain why the `match` or `term` query keep failing ? I'm running out of idea about what is happenning and i'm quite new to elasticsearch and logstash.

**Versions of tools and environment :**

- **OS:** RHEL Server 6.5 (Santiago)
- **Java:** 1.7.0_91
- **Elasticsearch:** 2.4.6

  - **Lucene:** 5.5.4
- **Logstash:** 2.4.1

Comment: The timestamp in your sample doc is in january, you filter on february documents

Comment: It was a copy paste error from my side, sorry ! The timestamp do exist in february and i do filter in february.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer, but it was to complicated to write this as a comment.

> from the mapping i know the field is not analysed.

You are searching for `ALERT_TYPE`, but this one is in fact analyzed with the [default analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/analysis-analyzers.html#default-analyzers) since you did not specify any analyzer directly under your ALERT_TYPE's mapping.

However, your ALERT_TYPE has an **internal** field named `raw` that is not analyzed. If you want to search documents using the raw field you'll need to change the query from

```
"must": [
    { "term": { "ALERT_TYPE": "ERROR" }}
]
```

to

```
"must": [
    { "term": { "ALERT_TYPE.raw": "ERROR" }}
]
```

Comment: Thanks you for the tip. I tried to filter on the raw field, it still didn't worked in that current case. I tried with both `match` and `term`.

But it do work on one of the other type i have on my indices in which I did not meet any problem (Using `term` on raw field). I never understood why i could never make the term filter work, now i understand why, thanks you !